# Adding textfields in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to create on a viewcontroller, textfields just by cliking on a button (number of clik on button = number of created textfields)?

Comment: It's possible for the view controller to handle the click, create buttons as a result and add them to a view, yes.

Comment: but how to reate these textfields just by cliking on the button

Comment: Please explain 'relate'. What do the text fields relate to?

Comment: [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...]

Comment: If you are asking is it it possible to create a uitextfield on the view by pressing a button that has the creation code in the ibaction method, then I assume it is possible. But not a very good practice.

Comment: but is it possible in a viewcontroller  to add several textfields ?, we need a scrollview .for me I have textfield1 , textxfiel2 and textfied3 .By pressing button I want to create 2 textfields under textfiel1 , by pressing it the second time , I will have textfield1 , and 4 textfields , textfield2 , textfield3 .The  number of created textfields depends on the number of clik , and they must be added below the first textfield

Comment: It's software, you can do pretty much anything you can imagine. It isn't clear what part of the process you're missing though. Go and try something then post the code if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`.h` file

`NSInteger i`;

`.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    i = 50;
}

- (void)btn_click
{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, i, 150, 22);
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
    i = i +50;
}
```

do you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty much possible.

Simply put "code to create text field" inside your btnClick method.
You can fire this btnClick method, any number of times you want.

Answer (score 0):

I will add something to the answer of @Vaibhav: **to assign a `tag` to each created button in order to identify them when necessary.**

In your .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) int tagCount
```

In your .m initialize it with any value (take care not to match this value with an already existing tag of your viewcontroller).

At @Vaibhav method:

```
- (void)btn_click
{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, i, 150, 22);
    [self.view addSubView:txt];
    i = i +50;

    //here comes the new lines to assign a tag to the new UITextFields
    txt.tag = self.tagCount;
    self.tagCount = self.tagCount + 1;
}
```

Hope it helps!